# Localization/Internationalization for Polymer 1.0

Tags: localization, internationalization, polymer, i18next

I'm looking into solutions for polymer 1.0 and yet I find it hard to understand how this works.
Found this https://github.com/Polymer/i18next-element which is unfortunately not even ready yet. Meanwhile I cannot figure out how to use i18next.I'm trying to combine all the info i can find, followed https://github.com/tabacha/javascript-i18n-example/blob/master/i18next/examle.html with any combinations from http://i18next.com/pages/sample.html and made sure to take a look at http://japhr.blogspot.gr/2014/02/getting-started-with-i18next-and-polymer.html .
The thing is, I seem to get wrong everything, even the very first initialization that imports the JSON filed needed. 
For starters the i18next is based on javascript functions that cannot work inside a polymer ready function due to syntax differences.

So my question is, am i getting something wrong or is this really that difficult to do with polymer? Anyone got a working example to share?

Trying to explain what I mean with an example, let's say that my polymer app has a list of all button labels in it, where the labels are stored in a language of selection JSON file.
so in the properties i got an empty buttons_list type: Array property.
then in ready: function() I follow the steps from the documentation (after having imported the i18next.js file of course)

```
var option = { resGetPath: '/localizeddata/english.json' };
          i18n.init(option);
var bvalue1 = i18n.t("buttons.value1");
var bvalue2 = i18n.t("buttons.value2");
this.buttons_list = {value1: bvalue1,value2: bvalue2}
```

buttons_list seems to be recognizing buttonvalue1 and 2 as undefined values.

PS: I've noticed many people use Dart, i haven't used it before, that is why so far i've only tried the solutions mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that internationalization/localization in Polymer 1.0 is indeed possible with i18next if a set of functions are properly used and scoped within the function that triggers the language selection event.

Within the language selection function, here's the syntax that I typed (with more detail)

```
somefunction: function(){    
  var option = { resGetPath: '/localizeddata/english.json' };
  i18n.init(option);
  (function(ok) {
    i18n.init(function(t) {
      arg = {
        var value1 = i18n.t("buttons.value1"),
        var value2 = i18n.t("buttons.value2")
      }
      ok.secondaryfunction(arg);
     });
  })(this);
}
secondaryfunction:function(n){
    this.buttons_list = n
}
```

This way what I get from within `secondaryfunction` is scoped from the whole page and used in `secondaryfunction` where (if double bound correctly) the collection stays updated.
Thing is, must be careful regarding when and how the functions load.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a straight answer to your problem but it's a solution nonetheless. We have made [our own i18n behavior](http://expandjs.com/elements/xp-i18n-behavior) in Polymer 1.0.

After an element implements the behavior you can write the template as follows:

```
<template>
    <span>[[localize('myString', locale)]]</span>
</template>
```

and it will search for the `myString` key in the `locale` object and return the localized string.

You can also call the method programmatically using `this.localize('myString', locale)`.

Answer (score 0):

I just published a simple (heavily in development) element (see it on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/quaintous-polymer/quaintous-i18n) or read about it [here](http://quaintous.com/2016/03/17/polymer-internationalization/)). It loads the translation files asynchronously and the usage is fairly simple:

```html
<!-- Import it in head -->
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/quaintous-i18n/quaintous-i18n.html">
<!-- initialize it in body -->
<quaintous-i18n locales-path="/locales/fa.json"></quaintous-i18n>
```

Now you can use it in various ways:

- In computed properties: just add `I18N` as your element [behavior](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html) and translate your data bindings, e.g. `{{__('hello')}}`
- In global context just use `I18N` object, e.g. `I18N.__('hello')`